# Repeat steps of a Spring Batch flow for each item of a list

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

How can I implement a Spring Batch job which has to read a list and then repeat one or more steps for each item in the list?

I am currently reading the list in the one step and then I put it in the job context. But the job context is persisted in the DB and if it gets too big, a CLOB has to be used and I do not have access to one.

So I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve storing the whole list on the job context.

Of course, I could simply put the list in a local variable. But I am curious whether there is a more Spring Batch-like option.

Comment: have you considered chaining item processors? http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#chainingItemProcessors

Comment: My job should like this:

1. read list
2. take one item from the list and do something with it
3. reader -> processor -> writer
4. if there are more items in the list, repeat from step 2

So I can't chain any processors.

Comment: That sounds like a fairly typical job process. Read -> Process -> Write. What am I failing to see the issue is?

Comment: It is a loop inside another loop. The first step produces a collection and for each item of this collection, the second step has to run a read-process-write task. For each item in the first collection, the second step reads another collection and has to iterate over it, process it and then write the results. I do not know how to explain this any better than this.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. The "Process" is the inner loop where you take one item from the read step, and do whatever is needed (expand to another list, process those items in turn), then write the result. I think you are trying to treat the "process" as steps in a batch when it shouldn't be.

Comment: I have the same need.  I do not want to re-read the data for each read/processor/write section.  I want to read and item with 2 lists of data and pass that to 1-10 additional steps.  each step will use the same data.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the comments above about structuring the job in the first place (which I tend to agree with), if you use the latest 3.0.0.M3, you can create a `JobScope`'ed container that could hold the collection as you loop through the various steps.  From there you can read/process/write to that container instead of an external source.

Comment: I can't use Spring Batch 3, so I do not have a job scope. The best solution I've found so far is to store the list in another collection tied to the job execution ID. In regard to the restructuring the job, I fail to see how this can help. I have a list, for each item I copy a remote file locally then I use a STAX reader to read it, next process and write each item to my DB. And I repeat this. I have too much data to store it in memory or to temporarily persist it in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed on [Spring Batch-Repeat step for each item in a data list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530652/spring-batch-repeat-step-for-each-item-in-a-data-list) question, [Partitioning](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning%20seems) seems to be the solution.

Configuration for PartitionHandler:

```
        <batch:step id="anyNameJobMaster">
            <batch:partition step="nameOfActualStepToBeIterated" partitioner="partitioner">
                <batch:handler grid-size="10" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
            </batch:partition>
        </batch:step>

       <bean id="partitioner" class="org.example.PartitionerThatImplementsPartitioner" lazy-init="true" scope="step"/>
```

PartitionHandler Sample Code:

```
public class PartitionerThatImplementsPartitioner implements Partitioner{
    @Override
    public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
         Map<String, ExecutionContext> map = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>(gridSize);  
         //Iteration goes here
         //For Each Iteration, create ExecutionContext and add it to map.
         map.put("somePartionKeyString", new ExecutionContext().put("ContextIdentifiere.g.FileName", "IteratedVale.g.FilePath"))

    }
}
```

Job Configuration:

```
     <batch:step id="nameOfActualStepToBeIterated">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="someTxManager">
            <batch:chunk processor="someProcessor"
                writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="${commitInterval}">
                <batch:reader>
                    <bean id="itemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
                        <property name="resource" value="#{stepExecutionContext['ContextIdentifiere.g.FileName']}" />                       
                    </bean>
                </batch:reader>
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
```